# jQuery UI Dialog - dialog() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to have a multiple input prompt box and used the [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) but I get an error saying that `.dialog()` is not a function.

[image: Type error]

What I'm trying to do is to prompt for a username and password before allowing all the users to access the "New Materials" tab.

**HTML**

```
<!--Code for the tab contents' divisions-->

<div id="dialog">
    <input type="text" id="input1" />
    <input type="text" id="input2" />
</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
function openTab(evt, divisionId) {
    if(divisionId=="addNewMaterial"){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            close: function(event, ui) {
                // do whatever you need on close
            }
        });
    }

    else {
        // Declare all variables
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
        document.getElementById(divisionId).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you included jquery to your webpage resources? Looks like not

Comment: Yes. I've actually included `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` and    `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>` in the head

Comment: Also probably the reason is that jquery dialog should be initialized when the document is loaded. I mean that usually all jquery stuff is executed in the `$(document).ready()`.
Probably you register your openTab() listener when jquery is not yet ready. But I am not sure.

Comment: Maybe that's thè issue.I'll try this and let you know. Thanks